# SAS data format to int format

Tags: sas

I have a date column in date format i.e. 05MAY1985. I would like a column with just the year, but in an int format as opposed to a date format.

So I have extracted just the year from the date by:

```
  year = date;
  FORMAT year YEAR4.;
```

Is there a way to get this year as an int? I have tried int(year) but that converts the year into the number of days since 1960.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying a format does not change the underlying value, just the way it is displayed. Try using the `year` function - e.g. `year = year(date);`.